# LaTeX 3 string variable with braces

Tags: expl3

I want to include some braces in my string variable:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \str_new:N \l_example_var
    \int_new:N \l_example_int

    \str_set:Nn \l_example_var {\{}
    \str_put_right:NV \l_example_var {\l_example_int}
    \str_put_right:Nn \l_example_var {\}~some~text}

    \str_show:N \l_example_var
    \ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately this results in the braces being preceded by pesky backslashes:

```
> \l_example_var=\{0\} some text.
<recently read> }

l.13 ^^I\str_show:N \l_example_var
```

How would I be able to get rid of the backslashes in front of the braces? E.g. `\l_example_var={0} some text.`

Comment: `\c_left_brace_str` and `\c_right_brace_str` instead of `\{` and `\}`, but are you sure you need `str` instead of a token list, i.e. `\tl_set:N...`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for the help. Using a token list would indeed seem more fitting. However doing `\tl_set:NV \l_example_tl { {\l_example_int} }` results in the surrounding braces disappearing.

Comment: `\tl_set:Nx \l_example_tl { { \int_to_arabic:n { \l_example_int } } }`

Comment: @tambre: Your use-case wasn't clear, I could have done a `\tl...` like solution as well...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what's the benefit of a string such as `{42}` and probably you need a token list instead. However,

```
\str_set:Nx \l_example_str { \c_left_brace_str \int_use:N \l_example_int \c_right_brace_str }
```

will do. For a token list it's similar

```
\tl_set:Nx \l_example_tl { { \int_use:N \l_example_int } }
```

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, the `{` and `}` 'strings' shall appear literally in the string, so one way to add them is to use `\c_left_brace_str` and `\c_right_brace_str` and the `V` modifier for the `\str_set:Nn` macro

There are other literal string constants such as `\c_hash_str` or `\c_dollar_str`, which are constant token lists with catcode 12 actually. See page 75 in the current `interface3` manual (as of 2018/12/27).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \str_new:N \l_example_var
    \int_new:N \l_example_int

    \str_set:NV \l_example_var \c_left_brace_str
    \str_put_right:NV \l_example_var \l_example_int
    \str_put_right:NV \l_example_var \c_right_brace_str
    \str_put_right:Nn \l_example_var {~some~text}


    \str_show:N \l_example_var
    \ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

The output is

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018)
>
> (preloaded format=pdflatex)  \write18 enabled. entering extended mode
>
> (./stringwith.tex LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
>
> (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
>
> Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
>
> (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
>
> (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
>
> (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
>
> (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3pdfmode.def))
>
> (./stringwith.aux)
>
> > \l_example_var={0} some text.  }
>
> l.16     \str_show:N \l_example_var
>
> ? x No pages of output. Transcript written on stringwith.log.

Comment: There should be no brace around a `V` argument. Not that braces make a difference, it's more on the conceptual side.